# Store a value in memory for an hour C#

Tags: c#

I need to store particular value in memory cache for one hour. After one hour automatically I will create another value and will assign in same memory.

Time to time value will be change and memory will replace with new value.

So how would I do this ? 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can use `Timer` to count time and you can use `Registry` or file to store value if your concern is how to keep value after software exit. Otherwise question is very unclear.

Comment: I think you are looking for Cache with SlidingExpiration of 60 minute.

Comment: @Novice Programmer, Yes I am looking for cache with expiration will be every 60 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) Class in .net framework 4 or above.

Answer (score 1):

[MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) fits your requirements nicely.